# Produce Statistic event with Kafka Stream and Windowed Stream, but skip some windowed if there is some more recent one

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

For the last 24 hours of events, I want to produce a statistic event to display it somewhere in real-time.
So, the current behavior is that one:

1. Every minute, I aggregate the last 24h event to add list object
2. I compute the full list temporarily and produce the final statistic object
3. I push this final statistic object to a new topic

I'm using for that Kafka Stream and Spring Boot.

It works well, I have the good calculation and the event is well produced in development. The problem is when I am in production, and the source event topic contains too much data.

If my application stop for one day or a few minutes. When application restart, my application try to recover the history. Kafka stream continues to process from the last offset and takes a huge time to catch up on his delay.
In fact, I don't care about history. I don't need the statistic object from yesterday or the last 24h minus 1h, I just want to recompute from NOW to the last 24h and that's it.

Same if the application is running properly, but with some delay to process the statistic event. The lag increase and increases. I would Kafka Stream automatically skip Time Windows and just compute the last one if the delay becomes too much important.

Do you think Kafka Stream can manage that?
Thanks in advance.

```
    /**
 * Every minute, we collect all events on the last day and we publish a new statistic event.
 * 
 * @param streamsBuilder
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public KStream<String, MySourceEvent> kstreamMySourceEventStatistique(final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {

    // We create the stream to consume machine-state topic.
    KStream<String, MySourceEvent> kstreamStat = streamsBuilder
            .<String, MySourceEvent>stream("my-source-topic", Consumed
                    .with(Serdes.String(), KafkaUtils
                            .jsonSerdeForClass(MySourceEvent.class)));

    // For this stream, every minute, we take all events in the last 24h, and we aggregate them into TemporaryStatistiqueEvent
    KTable<Windowed<String>, TemporaryStatistiqueEvent> aggregatedStream = kstreamStat 
            .groupByKey(Grouped
                    .with(Serdes.String(), KafkaUtils
                            .jsonSerdeForClass(MySourceEvent.class)))
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows
                    .of(Duration.ofDays(1))
                    .advanceBy(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                    .grace(Duration.ofSeconds(0)))
            .<TemporaryStatistiqueEvent>aggregate(() -> new TemporaryStatistiqueEvent(), (key, value, logAgg) -> {
                logAgg.add(value); //I add the event in my TemporaryStatistiqueEvent object
                return logAgg;
            }, Materialized
                    .<String, TemporaryStatistiqueEvent, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("temporary-stats-store")
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(KafkaUtils.jsonSerdeForClass(TemporaryStatistiqueEvent.class))
                    .withRetention(Duration.ofDays(1)))
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()));
    // Now, we gave an aggregate on last 24h, we compute the statistic and push FinalStatisticEvent object in a new topic
    aggregatedStream
            .toStream()
            .map(new KeyValueMapper<Windowed<String>, TemporaryStatistiqueEvent, KeyValue<String, PlcStatMachineState>>() {
                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, FinalStatisticEvent> apply(final Windowed<String> key, final TemporaryStatistiqueEvent temporaryStatistiqueEvent) {
                    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(key.window().end()), ZoneOffset.UTC);
                    return new KeyValue<>(key.key(), temporaryStatistiqueEvent.computeFinalStatisticEvent(zdt));
                }
            })
            .to("final-stat-topic", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), KafkaUtils.jsonSerdeForClass(FinalStatisticEvent .class)));

    return kstreamStat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky question...

For the offline and restart case, what you could try is to manipulate the start offsets (ie, commmitted offsets) before you restart the app. Using `bin/kafka-consumer-group.sh` you can "seek by time" and thus "skip forward to now-minus-24h".

For the case when the app lags, it's more complicated. Maybe you could have a "dynamic filter" (to access the record metadata like its timestamp you could use `flatTransformValues` to implement the filter) as first step in your program, that drops records that are too old?